# What happened to PowerShell ISE?

Tags: windows-8, powershell

Where is PowerShell ISE in Windows 8?

In Windows 7, it was right on the Start Menu, but it doesn't appear anywhere in Windows 8.

Comment: You find this the same way in Windows 8 as in Windows 7: either go to Start and search for it or go to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools`

Comment: @CalebJares: It doesn't show up anywhere in Start Search

Comment: Strange, [this is what it brings up for me](http://imgur.com/8F3xm).

Comment: @CalebJares: I don't get that.

Comment: That's odd, do you have Windows 8 Pro release? 64 or 32 bit? Did you accidentally delete it?

Comment: @CalebJares: Pro, x64, fresh install.  No.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's still there, but it's hidden in Program Files.

To get it back, do the following:

1. From the Start screen, type `powershell_ise`
2. Right-click on `powershell_ise.exe`, then click `Pin to Start`
3. Return to the Start Screen
4. Right-click the new `powershell_ise` entry at the end, and click `Open File Location`
5. Rename the shortcut to `Windows PowerShell ISE` (or whatever you prefer)

---

You can also find it in the Administrative Tools folder.

Comment: Interesting. It cannot find it without fullname.